# How to create a footer below the main content?

Tags: svelte, carbon-components, carbon-components-svelte

I'm using carbon components for Svelte and would like to know how I can add a footer to the bottom of the page

```
<Header>
    <!-- navbar content -->
</Header>

<Content>
    <slot /> <!-- renders router view -->
</Content>

<!-- Footer should go here ( at the bottom ) -->
```

I wasn't able to find a "footer" component. Another solution would be expanding the main content to the bottom of the page even if there is very little content, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add a container or override the styles for content to take more vertical height.

Personally, I put the footer inside the content so it is pushed aside if there is a side navigation (analogous to the [Carbon design system website](https://carbondesignsystem.com/)).

Example:

```
<Content class="content flex column items-stretch">
    <div class="flex-grow">
        <Grid>
            <Row>
                <Column>
                    <p>Content</p>
                </Column>
            </Row>
        </Grid>
    </div>

    <footer class="flex-constant">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </footer>
</Content>

<style>
    :global(.flex) { display: flex; }
    :global(.flex.column) { flex-direction: column; }
    :global(.flex.items-stretch) { align-items: stretch; }
    :global(.flex-grow) { 
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    :global(.flex-constant) { 
        flex-grow: 0;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    :global(.content) {
        padding: 0;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 3rem); /* 3rem = header */
    }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ccbd834684e94e5ab3b348dc71e4b1a8?version=3.55.1)

(I usually use utility classes for flex layout which are in a global stylesheet, so here I added them via `:global`. Classes on the Carbon components have to be `:global` or at least use something like `.local-element :global(.class-on-component)` to scope it again.)

This setup makes the `Content` take at least space equivalent to the height of the viewport with the ability to grow beyond (the footer is not fixed). Using a vertical flex box, the router content takes all free space, pushing the footer to the bottom if the page is not filled.

Note that using `vh` can cause various headaches with mobile browsers and their use of the address bar. There should be questions on SO that explain that in more detail. Also, new [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#relative_length_units_based_on_viewport) (`sv*`/`lv*`/`dv*`) have been added to deal with this issue, but implementation may still be lacking (see [this HTTP 203 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xl9R8aTOW_I) for an in-depth explanation).

The REPL will cause additional overflow due to the console panel at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [carbon design systems website](https://carbondesignsystem.com/components/UI-shell-header/usage/), looks like the Design System does not use a footer. A footer-like element exists in this website, but it's contained in the right panel (and the left panel persists, even when the footer scrolls in), like just another section in a hero page.

As you can see, they only have UI Shells for headers, left panels and right panels.
[image: Carbon Design System website menu showing UI Shell Header, UI Shell Left Panel, UI Shell Right Panel]

If you plan on religiously following the design system, I do not recommend setting up a footer unlike the one they use on their website. If you still do want to, however, I hope H. B.'s answer will suffice.